# Changing color statements in Viewholder don't work; only one statement works properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make an adapter for recyclerview listen click event and change color of text and edittext.
When I add just

```
text.settextView.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("~~"));
```

it works properlybut when I use `if-else` and add

```
text.settextView.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("~~"));
```

it doesn't work... At first I thought some statement is skipped, so I added `Log.i` to check, and I think there are no skipped statements.

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            public  MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener2;
            TextView textView;
            EditText editText;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener2) {
                super(itemView);
                textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                editText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                this.myCustomEditTextListener2=myCustomEditTextListener2;
                this.editText.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener2);
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int pos=getAdapterPosition();
                        if(swtich==0) {   //swtich is defined in adapter class(static int swtich=0;)
                            Log.i("info", "click event & swith");
                            textView.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#e1bee7"));
                            //editText.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF1FF"));
                            swtich = 1;
                        }else if(swtich==1){


                            textView.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                            editText.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                            swtich=0;}


                        if(pos!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            if(mListener!=null){
                                mListener.onItemClick(view,pos);


                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Where did you define `swtich`? What is its value? (You only test for exactly 0 and 1, can it be something else?)

Comment: i add it on top.                                                                                                       public class webadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<webadapter.ViewHolder>  {
static int T=0;
ArrayList<data> list =new ArrayList<data>();

Comment: Accepted answer notes that this was an `else if` instead of an `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. You need to else condition (instead of if-else):

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos=getAdapterPosition();
            if(swtich==0) {   //swtich is defined in adapter class(static int swtich=0;)
                Log.i("info", "click event & swith");
                textView.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#e1bee7"));
                editText.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF1FF"));
                swtich = 1;
            }else{
                textView.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                editText.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                swtich=0;
            }


            if(pos!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                if(mListener!=null){
                    mListener.onItemClick(view,pos);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```